# Fine Uploader - get image date

Tags: fine-uploader

Is there a way to obtain (on the client side) the creation/last modification date of an image uploaded via FineUploader? Looking for a solution for JPEGs (where EXIF is available) and PNGs(where EXIF is not available).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to determine these values for non- jpegs.  For jpegs, you can use a client side EXIF parser, like, https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js to extract this data.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the usage of something like $(this).fineUploaderS3('getFile', id).lastModifiedDate in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926058/fineuploader-harvest-original-last-modified-date-when-uploading-to-amazon-s3

Is this something that we can use? I guess this too is for jpegs only?

Comment: @SayanBhattacharyya yes you can, but it refers to the actual file's last modified time, whereas the exif parser would enable you to get the dates stored in the EXIF saved with the image. So, if EXIF is not available, you can use `getFile` and `lastModifiedDate` to get the last modified date, but it will refer to a different date.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to use that for PNGs anyway!